# Case Statements in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, data-warehouse, mdx-query

I need to create a calculated measure `Internal Quantity` for the following equation,

```
Internal quantity = Quantity where [X].[Category Id] = A or B/ Quantity
```

The calculated measure `Quantity` calculates the SUM of a column. So, for example if the values for `[X].[Category Id].&[A] = 50` and `[X].[Category Id].&[A] = 20` and the `Quantity = 100`, the `Internal Quantity` should be 0.5 and 0.2 respectively.

I have written the following MDX expression to achieve this,

```
Case [X].[Category Id]
   When [X].[Category Id].&[A] Then [X].[Category Id].&[A]/[Measures]. 
   [Quantity]
   When [X].[Category Id].&[B] Then [X].[Category Id].&[B]/[Measures]. 
   [Quantity]
   else NULL
   End
```

However with the above expression both the `[X].[Category Id].&[A]` and `[Measures].[Quantity]` return the same value probably as they are inside a case statement.

I would really appreciate any help with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understand correctly then different categories requires different calculation over the measure. Do you think you can achieve this via the underlying SQL (Either way the result would be [Internal Quantity] = [quantity] / Category_div, and for categories which are not A or B it's NULL). Alternatively and in order to DEBUG, get the results of the Category_ID and Measure.quantity on your MDX just to find out what's going on

Comment: It may be worth looking at using `.CurrentMember` in this situation, rather than specifically mentioning [A] and [B] every time. I'm sorry I cannot be any more helpful than that. You might be able to find examples of CurrentMember being used in similar situations.